# C file turns to C++ file in VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code

My C file turns into a C++ file whenever the code is saved (or any other file it uses). Doesn't help when I manually change the language.

I tried changing the name, and it worked. But this is for a university assignment, so the name is absolutely crucial, and this specific name makes VSCODE think it's a C++ file. I tried manually changing the language, as mentioned before, but that didn't do a thing.

Comment: what do you mean? what are you seeing that makes you think that? Are you talking about the language mode indicator in VS Code's status bar? what is your file named?

Comment: Yes. The name of the file is "ex_5.c", and it changes it to be cpp code. When I change the name to "ex_5_change_name" it correctly reads it as C code.